# Apk file opens with another program on windows. How do I change it so that it opens with the default program?

Tags: apk

I've accidently changed how apk files open on my pc to notepad. I've tried to change it back to the default program, but unfortunately cannot remember what it was. Can anybody help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The issue was not how to run an apk file. The issue was when I right click the apk file, it gave me options to decompile. As I accidently changed how to open the apk file to notepad, those options were unavailable. After an hour of googling with no luck, I decided to do a system restore to the previous day which restored my apk files to how they were originally. The right click options were available and therefore my problem was solved.

Comment: Hii Loui,i also struck with same problem,could you give me step by step process to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open "Notepad" App by typing Notepad in Search Box and type cd.

Step 2: Click on "File".

Step 3: Click on "Save as".

Step 4: Select Desktop as the destination.

Step 5: Select "All Files" option in  "Save as Type."

Step 6: Give name to the file as "abc.bat" without quotes.

Step 7: Click on "Save" button.

Step 8: Now, Right click on any file that you want to change association to unknown.

Step 9: Choose "Open with".

Step 10: Click on "Choose another App".

Step 11: Click on "More Apps" and then check the box Marked "Always use this App".

Step 12: Scroll down and click on "Look for another app on this PC."

Step 13: Navigate to Desktop and select "abc.bat" file, and then click on 'open' button, you might get message "This app can't run on your PC", just click on Close.

Step 14: Finally, delete the abc.bat file from your desktop.

Step 15: Restart the computer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0gdcOL7Ne0

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help [file.downlaodatoz.com](http://file.downloadatoz.com/apk-file-extension/)

By right-clicking on the .apk file while the shift button is pressed, you'll get an "Open with..." option. On the dialog that will be opened, you'll find a link to search the internet for a appropriate program to use.

Comment: Hi Dev.Jaap I tried that plus the link you provided this morning. Still no luck

Comment: Loui - apk is the installation file for android as far as I know. Maybe you can find an appropriate program for opening/running the android application by using google. I don't know if you have had ever a default program for opening .apk files, I my registry no program is registered for opening .apk files, so maybe you have only assigned a program for opening an .apk and did not overwrite the default one. Otherwise try one of programs in your Android SDK or try reinstalling the SDK....

Comment: Problem solved. The issue was not how to run an apk file. The issue was when I right click the apk file, it gave me options to decompile. As I accidently changed how to open the apk file to notepad, those options were unavailable. After an hour of googling with no luck, I decided to do a system restore to the previous day which restored my apk files to how they were originally. The right click options were available and therefore my problem was solved.